# Php não se conecta ao banco de dados (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

Então, comecei recentemente com o php e tentei fazer um crud simples com php+mysql mas, tive um problema que acredito ser na conexão com o mysql. 
ao carregar a ação (action) no html, a página fica em branco. Não retorna erro nem insere no banco. Segue o script abaixo:

```
       <form class="central text" name="cadastro" method="post" action="cadastro.php">
        <div>
            <h2>Dados Pessoais</h2>
            <p>Primeiro Nome</br><input type="text" name="primeiroNome"></p>
            <p>Sobrenome</br><input type="text" name="sobrenome"></p>
            <p>Nascimento</br><input type="date" name="nascimento"></p>
            <p>Nacionalidade</br><input type="text" name="nacionalidade"></p>
        </div>
        <input name="salvar" type="submit" value="Salvar">
    </form>
```

O teste simples, só pra saber se está conectando. Está sem a query de inserção no banco, porque não passa sequer dessa linha de conexão:

```
<?php

$conexao = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") 
echo "Conectado!";
    or die("Não conectado ao banco! Erro: ".mysql_error());
?>
```

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar. 
Só pra constar:
1-Sim, pra chegar até aqui e perguntar a alguém, eu pesquisei bastante!
2-Estou usando o Linux (LAMP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrão não usa mysql_ não, essa função está obsoleta... Tenta isso: tem várias formas de conexão, eu uso assim...

```
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$banco = 'test';
$con = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
if ($con->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}else{
echo "Conectou !!";
} 
?>
```

Vê se dá certo, qualquer coisa comenta que agente ajusta...

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado. 
Todos os lugares que pesquisei, ensinava da forma que eu estava fazendo. Mas enfim, muito obrigado!